# JHipster in 12 minutes -- problems

Tags: angular, datepicker, jhipster

First time using JHipster.  Looks pretty awesome, but have a problem with [Matt Raible's 12 minute video: Get Started with JHipster 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRREt1KB4Y8) (showcased on the web site front page)

I am running JHipster on the latest version of openSUSE (linux) with IntelliJ IDEA for the IDE.  I followed carefully his instructions, and broadly speaking everything works, but I have a problem.

The blog application fails to create a datepicker UI element for the entry edit page.  A date field is created in the database, but it is rendered on screen as a text string (appears to be ISO format e.g.2017-11-30T08:09:00) which can be edited as such, but is not very friendly.  Matt Raible's video shows a datepicker, but I don't get one.  Anyone know why?

Cheers!

**PS**: FireFox v52.5.0; Node v3.10.10; Yarn v1.3.2; using gradle, and compiling/launching by clicking the 'Run' button within IntelliJ  (which pops the browser open at localhost:8080).  No obvious errors appear in the console.

After I rebuild/run, my IntelliJ run window ends with:

```
Application 'blog' is running! Access URLs:
Local:      http://localhost:8080
External:   http://127.0.0.1:8080
Profile(s):     [swagger, dev]
```

*Also*,
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-915-b12 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.92-31-default

After that, I run 'yarn start' from the command line and open the browser at localhost:9000

Happy to add whatever additional information necessary to help get things moving...

**PPS**: Repeated steps on a Windows 10 64-bit machine, and exactly the same thing happens.

**No datepicker.**  Any ideas, anyone...?

Comment: Your question lacks details. Are you running BOTH yarn start and mvnw/gradlew? Are you accessing port 9000 (the one from yarn start) in browser? Which browser? Which Node version? Do you see some error in browser's console? Please edit your question rather than commenting below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! Wow!

Out of curiosity (and after thinking about Mr. Marziou's set of questions in his comment), I tried using a different browser (Opera v48.0.2685.52), and... I get a datepicker!

It seems the datepicker that comes "out-of-the-box" with JHipster doesn't work with Firefox (including the latest version: 57.0.1 64-bit).  Would have been nice if that was documented somewhere up front.

Thanks for your comments, Mr. Marziou!

Comment: There is an opened ticket https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6711 but can you try to use the latest version of Firefox ? it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the information Mr Grimaud.  I'll pay attention to that ticket, and look forward to seeing a resolution.  In the meantime, I'm sorry to report that the latest version of Firefox (v57.0.1 64-bit) shares in the same problem -- _no datepicker!_

Comment: I confirm totally your issue, it's because datetime-local is not supported in Firefox. Maybe using Datepicker+Timepicker? It should do the job

Comment: I was just checking back in on this issue (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6711)... @JulienDubois closed the ticket June 2018, but for me the issue persists. No go in Firefox v66.0.5!!